# Issue with some characters in the splitting strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is the stored procedure

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    AgentId,
    CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(States, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS States,
    CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Products,'&','&amp;'), ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS Products
FROM @tbVendor
 )
  ,FinalList AS (
SELECT 
AgentId,
RTRIM(LTRIM (sTable.sColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS States,
RTRIM(LTRIM (PTable.PColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS Products
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY States.nodes('//r') AS sTable(sColumn) 
CROSS APPLY Products.nodes('//r') AS PTable(PColumn) 
)
SELECT DISTINCT F.Products AS ProductName
   ,T.ProductId AS ProductId       
FROM FinalList F
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ProductId FROM @tbProduct TP WHERE TP.ProductName = F.Products) AS          T
 WHERE F.States = 'New York'
 AND F.AgentId = 1
 ORDER BY T.ProductId ASC
```

This is the SQL fiddle

http://rextester.com/SVXKFH57654

It is working fine and perfectly but it eliminate the records with "-" character in ProductName feild For e.g Non-Stick Utensils... etc

I am not able to tackle this issue... Please help me!!!

Comment: None of the records in your Fiddle have a "-" character in them.

Comment: Your Fiddle has no products containing "-", so I edited it changing "A.C" to be A-C" in 3 places and ran it. It worked fine.

Comment: Please try adding "-" in this fiddle but in actuall sql server it's not working like this...

Comment: I have just run this code on my local server changing T.V to T-V with no problems.

Comment: Post what actually isn't working into a Fiddle.  Multiple people have already tried putting a "-" into what you posted and have stated they can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: No doubt it works fine in fiddle but in actuall server it isn't working... let me say for these "Dental Services,Non-Resident Reciprocal" only Dental Service is  being fetched...

Answer (score 0):

For the splitting string you use XML. In this case, you will have problems with some characters. For example &, <, >. You can avoid this by using another method of splitting a string

Table function splitting strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStr] (
    @str varchar(MAX)
    ,@sep char(1)=','
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split ( n1, n2) 
    AS 
    ( 
    SELECT CAST(0 as bigint) as n1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @str + @sep) as n2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT n2 as n1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @str + @sep, n2 + 1) as n2
    FROM Split
    WHERE n2 < LEN(@str)
    )

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, n1+1, n2-n1-1) as Col FROM Split
)
GO
```

Using this function:

```
SELECT
    tbVendor.AgentId
    ,States.Col as States
    ,Products.Col as Products
FROM @tbVendor as tbVendor
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitStr](States, ',') as States
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitStr](Products, ',') as Products
```

this is equivalent to your code

```
-- First convert all comma separated data into tabular form as:
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        AgentId,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(States, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS States,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(Products, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS Products
    FROM @tbVendor
)
SELECT 
    AgentId,
    sTable.sColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS States,
    PTable.PColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Products
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY States.nodes('//r') AS sTable(sColumn) 
CROSS APPLY Products.nodes('//r') AS PTable(PColumn)
```